Atomically, what's the difference between annealing, tempering, & quenching?
Atomically, what's the difference between annealing, tempering, & quenching?
After watching Steve Mould's video on metal heat treatment (https://youtu.be/xuL2yT-B2TM), and near the end, he makes a comment on how his model is closer to annealment than to quenching or tempering, how are they different, at least atomically?

Do you know their difference when described macroscopically?

Sorry 'bout that Mauricio, not too much, 'cept that the larger crystalline structure is more tolerant to plastic deformation.

It doesn't answer your question, but you might like this video from Alpha Phoenix - Why are metals so stretchy?

This question really belongs in a material science/engineering forum. In general, all three of these heat treatments create micro-grains and or lock a metal into a specific phase in a controlled manner. There is no real atomic change in the metal.

Yeah, that's what I meant by atomically, sorry. That answer does help me a little though, thanks.

@StevanV.Saban I think the usage of the word 'atomic' by the OP is appropriate here. I count 'atomic level' as: the level of atom-to-atom interactions. Changes at that level are changes in how atoms bind to each other. When we want to refer to changes of the very atoms (as distinct from how atoms bind to each other) then we refer to that as 'change at the nuclear level'.

The device that Steve Mould built (a recreation of Atomix demonstration device) demonstrates only a specific aspect of crystallographic properties that are affected by heat and by rate of cooling.
The atoms of Iron alloys can end up in different types of crystallographic arrangement, depending on heat and rate of cooling, and those different crystallographic arrangements are distinct enough to get different names assigned to them, such as austenite and martensite. Those differences are out of scope of the Atomix demonstration device.
Other than the crystallographic differences there is the property of grain size.
In the video Steve Mould explains in what way the grain size affects the plasticity of the metal. "it takes less energy to move dislocations through a grain than it does to move grains against each other"
Link to 4:37 into the video: Dislocations


I took a quick look at the wikipedia article about Martensite
As I understand it: above a certain temperature the Carbon atoms in steel have enough freedom to go to an even distribution. When that steel cools again there is formation of regions where the Carbon atoms are in a 1-to-3 ratio with Iron atoms, and regions that are comparitively depleted of Carbon atoms. When the cooling is slow there is sufficient time to cause significant distinction between areas of cementite ($\text{Fe}_3\text{C}$) and depleted areas. With rapid cooling there isn't enough time for the Carbon atoms to migrate.
So that is - at atomic/crystallographic level - why quenching is out of scope of the Atomix demonstration device. In the Atomix device all the balls are the same, and there is one (crystallographic) arrangement that takes up far less volume than any other: hexagonal.
Also, with the Atomix device it is gravity that provides the tendency of the balls to pack together tightly; the balls don't have an interaction going on. On the other hand, in an actual metal there are interactions between the atoms that make the atoms stick together, and arrange into particular crystallographic structure. When cooled down rapidly: even when a lower energy crystallographic arrangement exists, at low temperature there is no opportunity to transition to that lower state.
(Incidentally: about transition to a lower energy state, with different crystallographic arrangement: there is the exceptional case of tin pest)

Thank you so much
